# Can't use gpp compiler in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, compiler-errors

I was trying to create a simple Hello World, and hit Ctrl+R to run the code, but it was using gcc, not gpp. (Gcc is the compiler for C, not C++!)

I opened `launch.json` and tried to change it to gpp, but it said it was already using gpp?

Comment: `g++` would be the C++ compiler, not `gpp`. `gpp` is a general-purpose preprocessor, not a compiler.

Answer (score 2):

```
gpp filename -o outputname
```

This will not work, as gpp is not the compiler name,

```
g++ filename -o outputname
```

This will work, as g++ is the name of compiler.

Comment: I made a mistake... I mean g++! I did use g++.

Comment: @anonymous show me the whole launch.json file.